# R remove elements randomly about 20% out of the data?

Tags: r

I have data as below. I want to keep them in order but remove 20% of its population.

How do I do in R

```
-44.1
-23.2
24.3
114.7
61.7
-19.4
-19.4
-19.4
-19.4
-30.6
32
75.1
40.4
-28.2
-28.2
-28.2
-28.2
67.3
36.2
-31.5
```

Comment: yes, thanks work very well.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have the vector `x` as your data:

```
set.seed(123)
x <- sample(1:100, 20)

> x
 [1] 29 79 41 86 91  5 50 83 51 42 87 98 60 94  9 77 21  4 27 78
```

Now you can choose a random 80% of `x` with:

```
x[sort(sample(1:length(x), length(x)*.8))]

[1] 29 79 41 86  5 83 51 42 87 98 60 94 77 21  4 27
```

The `sample(1:length(x), length(x)*.8)` will generate a vector of positions with the length of 80%  of your data, the `sort()` will keep the order of your data the way it is.

Comment: Hi LAP, Can the 80% data is random?

Comment: Yeah, the `sample()` function chooses randomly (the random selection can be made reproducible by setting a specific random seed with `set.seed()`).